# Using `Task.WhenAll` with `INotifyCompletion`

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have a custom operation, which implements the `GetAwaiter` method, which returns a custom object which implements `INotifyCompletion`.

`Task.WhenAll` only support instances of `Task`. Is there any way to wrap a task around a `INotifyCompletion`?

Edit: The reason is I want to await multiple of them.

Comment: `Is there any way to wrap a task around a INotifyCompletion`, yes, but are you wanting to wrap all tasks into a `INotifyCompletion`; basically when all task are done then notify?

Comment: No. I basically want to be able to mix and match `INotifyCompletion` and tasks into a `Task.WhenAll` call.

Comment: Maybe use `TaskCompletionSource`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question. I solved it by adding the following method to my class, which has the `GetAwaiter` method.

```
public async Task GetTask() {
    await this;
}
```

Then I can call `Task.WhenAll(myCustomAwaitableObject.GetTask())`.