# how can I combine await.WhenAny() with GetAwaiter extension method

Tags: c#, async-await, extension-methods

I want to `await` a `button.click()` event. For that created an extension `GetAwaiter()` method:

```
public static class ButtonAwaiterExtensions
{
    public static ButtonAwaiter GetAwaiter(this Button button)
    {
        return new ButtonAwaiter()
        {
            Button = button
        };
    }

    public class ButtonAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
    {
        public bool IsCompleted
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public void GetResult()
        {

        }

        public Button? Button { get; set; }

        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            RoutedEventHandler? h = null;
            h = (o, e) =>
            {
                Button!.Click -= h;
                continuation();
            };
            Button!.Click += h;
        }

    }
}
```

(I found it here: http://blog.roboblob.com/2014/10/23/awaiting-for-that-button-click/)

With that I can await the `Button1.Click()` event directly with `await Button1;` which is great.

**BUT I couldn't figure out how to combine this awaitable with someting like** `await Task.WhenAny()`

I tried

> await Task.WhenAny(Button1, Button2);

It will tell me that it "cannot convert from Button to Task".

I thougt I found the solution here:
[Using `Task.WhenAll` with `INotifyCompletion`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64554979/using-task-whenall-with-inotifycompletion) by just adding a method

```
public static async Task GetTask()
{
    await this;
}
```

to my ButtonAwaiterExtensions class, but the keyword `this` cannot be used in my static class.

**I cannot figure out what to return in the method or generally how to `await` any `Button.Click()`. Any ideas?**

Comment: I recommend reading about Tasks and asynchronous programming in C#. What you want to achieve could be done using the Task Asynchronous Pattern: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/implementing-the-task-based-asynchronous-pattern. What you cannot do is await methods that do not return asynchronous Tasks.

Comment: Try creating an additional extension method `async Task AsTask(this Button self) => await self` and use it like `await Task.WhenAny(button1.AsTask(), button2.AsTask())`. Maybe this works.

Comment: My question to you: What do you actually want to achieve? Why do you want to await the execution of the Button.click() method?

Comment: @ewerspej this is meant for creating tutorials on the UI. Another example is found in the same blog as mentioned above (BUT also with a strict click-order which I do not want): http://blog.roboblob.com/2014/10/25/using-await-to-build-cool-ui-tutorials/

Comment: So you need to make then Click handlers awaitable, that might be possible in the way that @SebastianSchumann provided in the comment above. What you might want to do in that case is use ```await Task.WhenAll(new List<Task>{ button1.AsTask(), button2.AsTask() } );``` instead of *WhenAny()*. *WhenAll()* will only return once all Tasks have completed.

Comment: @SebastianSchumann thank you. That worked. Small adjustment, great success! :-)

Comment: @ewerspej  `Task.WhenAny` oder `Task.WhenAll` work directly without `new List<Task>`. Not necessary. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Sebastian Schumann comment ([how can I combine await.WhenAny() with GetAwaiter extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73959407/how-can-i-combine-await-whenany-with-getawaiter-extension-method)) I solved my problem by adding another extension method directly to my ButtonAwaiterExtensions class:

```
public async static Task AsTask(this Button self) => await self;
```

Complete solution:

```
public static class ButtonAwaiterExtensions
{
    public static ButtonAwaiter GetAwaiter(this Button button)
    {
        return new ButtonAwaiter()
        {
            Button = button
        };
    }

    public class ButtonAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
    {
        public bool IsCompleted
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public void GetResult()
        {

        }

        public Button? Button { get; set; }

        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            RoutedEventHandler? h = null;
            h = (o, e) =>
            {
                Button!.Click -= h;
                continuation();
            };
            Button!.Click += h;
        }
    }
   public async static Task AsTask(this Button self) => await self;
}
```

An alternative (little shorter) Implementation for `GetAwaiter` might be:

```
public static TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter(this Button self)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(self);
    TaskCompletionSource tcs = new();
    self.Click += OnClick;
    return tcs.Task.GetAwaiter();

    void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        self.Click -= OnClick;
        tcs.SetResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: @SebastianSchuhmann thank you for the shorter version. Works flawless :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thx for the simplifications - but why did you remove the question mark from `object sender`? The [`EventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=net-6.0) enforces the sender to be nullable and if we build our projects with all warnings as errors no project will build without that question mark.

Comment: @SebastianSchumann as far as I know most projects are compiled without `#nullable enable`, and the question marks generate warnings in those projects. But if you prefer then you could edit the question mark back.