# How can I await for a button click in an async method?

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, button, extension-methods

I try to write a code to read a JSON File and allows user to input all the parametes for the objects in the JSON File one by one.
I try to write something like an "awaitable Button", but I failed to write a "GetAwaiter" extension for the button, although I found informations about how to do it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-inherit-from-existing-windows-forms-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

[how can I combine await.WhenAny() with GetAwaiter extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73959407/how-can-i-combine-await-whenany-with-getawaiter-extension-method)

http://blog.roboblob.com/2014/10/23/awaiting-for-that-button-click/

So here is my code after clicking a button "loadJSON":

```
for (int i = 0; i<templist_net.Count; i++)
{
    GeneratorFunctions.GetNetworkParameterList(templist_net[i].Type, templist_net[i], treeViewPath.SelectedPath, SolutionFolder);
    cBoxPouItem.Text = templist_net[i].Type;

    ListViewParam2.ItemsSource = GeneratorFunctions.TempList;   // Parameter list binding
    temp = GeneratorFunctions.TempList;
    ListViewParam2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;             // Set list 2 visible
    ListViewParam.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;            // Set list 1 invisible

    //something stop loop, and wait user to type parameters in Listview, and click Button, Then the loop move on. 
}
```

And Here is code trying to write a Button with extension. I add a new class for custom control, and write the extension.

```
public partial class CustomControl2 : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
    static CustomControl2()
    {

    }
    public static TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter(this Button self)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(self);
        TaskCompletionSource tcs = new();
        self.Click += OnClick;
        return tcs.Task.GetAwaiter();

        void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            self.Click -= OnClick;

            tcs.SetResult();
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't write a extension, which inherit System.Windows.Forms.Button. What should I do?

UPDATE:
here is what i tried.

```
 private async Task Btn_loadJsonAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        // Initialize an open file dialog, whose filter has a extend name ".json"
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "(*.json)|*.json";
        TextBoxInformation.Text += "Opening project ...\n";
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        { 
            networks = GeneratorFunctions.ReadjsonNetwork(openFileDialog.FileName);
            for (int i = 0; i < networks.Count; i++)
            {
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    if (networks[i].Type == "Network")
                    {
                        templist_net.Add(networks[i]);
                        i = 1;
                    }
                    if (networks[i].Type == "Subsystem")
                    {
                        templist_sub.Add(networks[i]);
                        i = 1;
                    }
                    if (networks[i].Type == "Component: Data Point Based Control")
                    {
                        templist_com.Add(networks[i]);
                        i = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            using (SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1))
            {
                void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => semaphore.Release();
                btn.Click += OnClick;

                for (int i = 0; i < templist_net.Count; i++)
                {
                    //...

                    //wait here until [btn] is clicked...
                    await semaphore.WaitAsync();
                }

                btn.Click -= OnClick;
            }}}
```

Comment: _"How can I wait for a button click event in a loop?"_ - You don't. That's the point of events. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I try to allow user to type information for objects one by one. So  I try to use await to stop the loop for a button click, which means user have typed the information. And the loop move on to the listview of next object.

Comment: http://blog.roboblob.com/2014/10/23/awaiting-for-that-button-click/ something like this

Comment: You might want to rethink your UI design. That's really not how that is supposed to work. Just because you _can_ force button clicks to be awaitable now doesn't mean you should. I really doubt this scenario is a reasonable use case for that.

Comment: What if I write a task " wait for user type and click ok" in the loop? Can I use task to stop the loop?

Comment: That's the point: You do not _"wait"_ in a GUI. You _act_ upon events. So that is: Button click => Open "Add Data" Form. Form's "OK" Button is clicked => Add Data from Form to a DataStructure ...

Comment: Extension methods need to be placed in a separate, static class, not inside a control deriving from button. Personally I think solutions like this can be fine. The alternative would be to create a state machine by hand, and that tend to result in code that is more complicated.

Comment: @Fildor but the thing is in JSON file, there are already all the objects to work with. My plan was click Button loadJSON. All the objets will be read and manuell type additional information one by one. I do need a loop to do all thing automatic, and type additional information in the screen is a step in the loop. So I think i need to stop the loop.

Comment: @JonasH I try to write a task instead write a extention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait for a button click asynchronously using a `SemaphoreSlim`, e.g.:

```
using (SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1))
{
    void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => semaphore.Release();
    btn.Click += OnClick;

    for (int i = 0; i < templist_net.Count; i++)
    {
        //...

        //wait here until [btn] is clicked...
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
    }

    btn.Click -= OnClick;
}
```

Comment: Thx. I tried it. And show the code in Update in my question. I don't know if i do it right. The system say it don't know what is sender and e in sentence "void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => semaphore.Release();" Can I write something with sender and RoutedEventArgs in a Methode, which already has sender and RoutedEventArgs?

Comment: `OnClick` is a [local funtion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077). What version of Visual Studio/C# are you using?

Comment: Visual studio 2017

Answer (score 0):

Although you may want to redesign the way you are doing things, a quick an dirty solution would be to use a dialog box in modal mode and upon the dialog box closing, capture the data that got input and continue looping. The loop will block until the dialog box is closed.

Comment: Ok, it make sense. But I try to use await or task to stop the loop.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I must insist that your request goes against the principles of the MVVM pattern which is based on events.
Your logic should be in a separate class and expose an `OnNext` method which should be called from the model through an [`ActionCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/design-tools/expression-studio-4/ff726423(v=expression.40))

Anyway, to conform (as much as possible) to the MVVM pattern, you don't want to `await` on the button but more on the command bound to the button.
So let's build an awaitable command :

```csharp
public class AwaitableCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly object _lock = new();
    
    private TaskCompletionSource? _taskCompletionSource;

    /// <summary>
    /// null-event since it's never raised
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { }
        remove { }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Always executable
    /// </summary>
    public bool CanExecute(object? parameter) => true;
    

    public void Execute(object? parameter)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_taskCompletionSource is null)
                return;

            _taskCompletionSource.SetResult();

            // reset the cycle
            _taskCompletionSource = null;
        }
    }

    public Task WaitAsync()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            // start a new cycle if needed
            _taskCompletionSource ??= new TaskCompletionSource();
            return _taskCompletionSource.Task;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can create your logic with it (I put it in the model, wich is a bad practice):

```csharp
public class Model : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private int _count;

    public Model()
    {
        RunLogicAsync();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get => _count;
        private set => Update(ref _count, value);
    }

    public AwaitableCommand OnNextCommand { get; } = new();
    
    /// <summary>
    /// I know, I know, we should avoid async void
    /// </summary>
    private async void RunLogicAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            for (;;)
            {
                await OnNextCommand.WaitAsync();
                Count++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And your view:

```xml
<Window ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:Model />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <system:String x:Key="StringFormat">You clicked it {0} times</system:String>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="{Binding Count}"
                ContentStringFormat="{StaticResource StringFormat}"
                Command="{Binding OnNextCommand}"
                Padding="10 5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Working demo available [here](https://github.com/Orace/SO/tree/main/SO_74626767).

Comment: Dude, I need to learn Lambda at first to understand ur answer. Thx.

Comment: There is no lambda, just [expression bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members), that just a way to write less code. But if you don't know this, that an indication that you shouldn't use `async` for this and make it work with an event driven solution.